# Different look between Google Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I work on list this list appear images the last image in the row look like has top margin in firefox but in Google Chrom look perfect
I am not good in English so this image explain what I mean :)

Image explain What I mean : http://filaty.com/i/alpha/74/74f4cb7180dd52b3d8d670bb31be8156

Html

```
<ul id="nwp_port_item" class="clearfix">
    <li class="mix webdesign"><img src="images/demo/e1.jpg"></li>
    <li class="mix graphics"><img src="images/demo/e2.jpg"></li>
    <li class="mix wordpress"><img src="images/demo/e3.jpg"></li>
    <li class="mix photography"><img src="images/demo/e4.jpg"></li>
    <li class="mix wordpress"><img src="images/demo/e5.jpg"></li>
    <li class="mix photography"><img src="images/demo/e6.jpg"></li>
    <li class="mix webdesign"><img src="images/demo/e1.jpg"></li>
    <li class="mix graphics"><img src="images/demo/e2.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
#nwp_port_item {
    margin:20px 0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    line-height:0;
}
#nwp_port_item li {
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin:1px;
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#nwp_port_item li img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

I use bootstrap to reset browser

Code on JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4t6Ch/

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4t6Ch/

Comment: your fiddle looks fine everywhere

Comment: When delete bootstrap.css everything look good !, I don't know where is the problem

Comment: So don't use bootstrap. If you need a reset, use [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or some else [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It is looks like image have some vertical-align.

Try to add some styles for image:

```
#nwp_port_item li img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display: block;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}
```